# jQuery get table width of cells and assign the same to different table of same location/index

Tags: jquery

I have started learning jQuery, but weak with syntax as of now.

I have two table's as below:-

```
<table class="tableone">
  <thead>
    <th width="30px">ID</th>
    <th width="150px">NAME</th>
    <th width="100px">Age</th>
  </thead>
</table>
<table class="tabletwo">
  <tbody>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>32</td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Where tableone has some dynamic width at run time. I need to get the width of column and assign the same to tabletwo same column index.

so, that after the code run's the HTML should be like :-

```
<table class="tabletwo">
  <tbody>
    <td width="30px">1</td>
    <td width="150px">John</td>
    <td width="100px">32</td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I was trying the same using jQuery where I was trying to loop thru the rows and get the width. While doing so, I can capture the index of the column and access the tabletwo. But I am not sure about the syntax.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  /* looping into the th*/
  $("table.tableone thead").find('th').each(function(index,value) {
    console.log(index);
    console.log(value);
  })   
});
```

Comment: `$("table.tableone tr")`, there is no `tr` in your HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(function(){
    var temp=$("table.tabletwo td");
    $("table.tableone th").each(function(i,v) {
        temp[i].width=v.width;
    });
})();
```

Comment: Thank you. I will accept your answer in 3 min. You are is a smart one.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```js
var firstTableWidth = [];

$('.tableone th').each(function(i, item) {
  firstTableWidth.push($(this).attr("width"));
})

$('.tabletwo td').each(function(i, item) {
  $(this).attr("width", firstTableWidth[i]);
})
```

```css
td {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tableone">
  <thead>
    <th width="30px">ID</th>
    <th width="150px">NAME</th>
    <th width="100px">Age</th>
  </thead>
</table>
<table class="tabletwo">
  <tbody>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>32</td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

You can inspect the second table and be sure, that all `width` attributes were applied properly. And I have added one CSS rule:

```
td {
  text-align: center;
}
```

It will center text of `td`'s in second table as it centered in first.